# imgur image hosting

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

I noticed that there was an informational message in the past few days about `imgur` having issues. Now I see that that message is no longer appearing, but when I try to upload an image I get:

> Failed to upload image; the image format is not supported

Here is a link to the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaTXa.png

I am trying upload PNG files from a Mac, generated exactly as I have in the past. I checked the `imgur` web site and they still list PNG as supported format.

So, is this an issue with imgur still experiencing problems, or is TeX.SE no longer allowing PNG files to be uploaded using the official method? If PNG is not longer supported i think a lot of Mac users are not going to be happy.

Comment: I uploaded a `.png` yesterday with no issues - not sure what you are seeing

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes I did yesterday as well. Just not today.  I'd do am image capture to show the exact error message, and post it but can't :-)

Comment: See chat, please!

Comment: Was this resolved? Or, if not, is it still happening?

Comment: Yes, just checked it now and seem to be working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed and seems to be working well for several days.